# how to vertical align jQuery button text?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've modifyed a bit the height of `ui-button`class but the text button remains at the bottom of it. How can I align it to the middle?

```
.ui-button {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   padding: 0px;
   margin-right: 0.1em;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: visible;
   // resize a bit the height
   height: 20px;
}
```

`vertical-align` didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/PM4T6/

Comment: Can you create a demo with jsfiddle?

Comment: try top,right,left and bottom css rule because you have position set for this dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.ui-button {line-height: 20px;}

Comment: Use less font-size. e.g: 10px. remove line-height and add padding:5px;

Answer (score 0):

When using `position` be sure to specify `top` `left`, `bottom` `right`....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.ui-button {
   display: table-cell;
   position: relative;
   padding: 0px;
   margin-right: 0.1em;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: visible;
   height: 50px;
}
```